# How to fix deprecation warning when setting on a slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I'm trying to add a year to each observation in a pandas dataframe until each observation is within a specified date range.

```
    for i in range(0,3):
        df.loc[df['date'] < "2023-06-01", 'date'] = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

I'm getting this warning.

```
DeprecationWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals`
will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting
a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either
`df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, 
`df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
```

How can I fix this? I've tried many things, but I can't seem to get around setting on a slice, and every method I try throws either the `DeprecationWarning` or `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Comment: It should be working for now, in future you have to adjust according to the Warning message.

Comment: You're using `df.loc[]`, right? But the error message mentions `iloc[]`. Can you double check that you're using loc when you got that error?

Comment: @NickODell Yes, I'm using df.loc[]. The error message applies to both df.loc and df.iloc. See [this update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#inplace-operation-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    df['date'].mask(df['date'] < '2023-06-01', 
                    df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this this alternative:

```py
import pandas as pd

mask = df['date'] < "2023-06-01"
df.loc[mask, 'date'] = df.loc[mask, 'date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Comment: This still gives a `DeprecationWarning`.